# Passing lambda declared using auto-keyword by non-const reference as argument to std::function parameter type

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

// passing function object by value
void foo(std::function<int(int, int)> f) {
    std::cout << f(3, 7) << std::endl;
}

// passing const function object by reference
void bar(const std::function<int(int, int)> & f) {
    std::cout << f(3, 7) << std::endl;
}

// passing non-const function object by reference
void fizz(std::function<int(int, int)> & f) {
    std::cout << f(3, 7) << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    std::function<int(int, int)> g1 = [] (int x, int y) { return x * y; };
    auto g2 = [] (int x, int y) { return x * y; };

    foo(g1);   // OK
    foo(g2);   // OK
    bar(g1);   // OK
    bar(g2);   // OK
    fizz(g1);  // OK

    // compile error:
    // error: invalid initialization of reference of type
    // 'std::function<int(int, int)>&' from expression of type
    // 'main()::<lambda(int, int)>'
    // error: in passing argument 1 of 'void fizz(std::function<int(int, int)>&)'
    fizz(g2);

}
```

Would someone explain to me:

(a) Why `fizz(g2)` generates a compile error, and the other constructs do not? It seems that I can pass a lambda by reference if I explicitly type out its type in its declaration, but not if I use the `auto` keyword, OR if I declare the function parameter type as `const`.

(b) What *does* `const` in the function parameter type mean here?

(c) <del>In what circumstances would I prefer to pass by value rather than reference</del> (UPDATE: now a separate question: [C++11: pass (lambda or other) function object by reference or value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984499/c11-pass-lambda-or-other-function-object-by-reference-or-value))?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `fizz(g1)` case, `g1` is already a `std::function`. Therefore, there is no need for an implicit conversion. So `fizz`'s parameter is a non-const reference to `g1`.

In `fizz(g2)`, `g2` is *not* a `std::function`. Therefore, the compiler must perform an implicit conversion. And the implicit conversion returns a *temporary*.

Temporary objects *cannot* be bound to non-const references; they can only bind to `const` references or values. Hence the compiler error.

> What does const in the function parameter type mean here?

You can only call `const` members of the object, you can not implicitly convert it to non-`const`, and you cannot perform non-`const` operations on its members.

You know, just like *any other use* of `const`.

Generally speaking, when a function takes a parameter by non-const reference, it is saying something very special about what it intends to do with that parameter. Namely, that you are handing it an object, and it is going to do non-const things with it (ie: modifying that object). That's why temporaries don't bind to non-const references; it's likely to be a mistake by the user, since the temporary may not update the original object you passed.

Unless `fizz` is actually going to modify the object, you should pass it either by value or by `const&`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not consider that a lambda was not of type std::function, so an implicit conversion to a temporary std::function was taking place. Also, for some reason, I guess I did not think that a std::function object could be modified, and thus the const was superfluous.

Comment: What is type `g2` then, if its not a `std::function`? Sure, it's a lambda, but how to type hint it in `fizz` then (considering we do not want to use std::function)?

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt: `g2` is a unique type whose name cannot be written by the user, just like all lambdas. Each lambda expression generates a unique type. The type of `g2` as a variable can be queried by `decltype(g2)`, but other than that, you aren't allowed to know what type it is.

Comment: @NicolBolas this answer has helped me grow in strength and in wiszdom.