# C++11: pass (lambda or other) function object by reference or value?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, lambda

This was originally part of this question:

[Passing lambda declared using auto-keyword by non-const reference as argument to std::function parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984453/passing-lambda-declared-using-auto-keyword-by-non-const-reference-as-argument-to)

but I decided to make it a separate one.

In what circumstances is it better/more idiomatic to pass a lambda or other function object by reference or value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use the same rules for "lambda"s that you would for *any* object that you take as a parameter.

A function should use non-const reference if the intent of the function is to modify the object for the caller. The function should use `const&` if it is just using the object without changing it. And it should pass by value if it is going to copy/move the object into its internal storage.

Comment: I remember reading in some comment on this forum that it was idiomatic to pass functors by value, and hence this question. I guess if there is a danger of the functor being passed going out of scope, then a by-value idiom is better.

Comment: If I pass a lambda by non-const reference, I can modify it. But what does "modify a lambda" mean?